# Reversing Google analytics ecommerce order and transaction

Tags: google-analytics, transactions

I am successfully using Google analytics ecommerce to track my orders/transactions but I am having difficulty reversing the test orders I have made.  I have followed the instructions as per Google and created the following plain HTML page to run and counter these transactions:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">
<head>
<title>Pilgrim 55</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />

<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxxx-x', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
</head>

<body>
<script>
ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');
ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
'id': '16',
'affiliation': 'Pilgrim 55',
'revenue': '-35.99',
'shipping': '0.00',
'tax': '0.00',
'currency': 'GBP'
});
ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
'id': '16',
'sku': 'p55serumfacialaloeretinol',
'name': 'Aloe Retinol Facial Serum',
'category': '',
'price': '35.99',
'quantity': '-1',
'currency': 'GBP'
});
ga('ecommerce:send');
ga('ecommerce:clear');
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

There are no js errors when I run this page. I have checked the transaction ID.

Basically, nothing happens in Google analytics.

Comment: No data will be updated in GA. Its just that the refund data will be shown

Comment: @tushar, he is not trying to send a refund, but trying to cancel the transaction out via a negative revenue. Sending refunds would require Enhanced E-Commcerce tracking.

Comment: @EikePierstorff What  I am trying to say is Reversing a transaction does not remove it. Both the original transaction and the reversal transaction are included in the transaction count.

Comment: Thanks Tushar.  There was a delay in it appearing in GA.  The code above works.